# is Greenplum is compatible with IPV6 Address

Tags: ipv6, greenplum

I just want to know whether greenplum supports IPV6 or not..

Will anyone help, that how and which version of Greenplum Supports IPV6 ?

One of my client worried, As per DOT and TRAI compliance requirement, all the application should support IPV6.

As Database Tier is handeled by Greenplum, Client wants to know whether greenplum is compatible with IPV6 or not, if not then required further road map

Comment: Not a programming question, asking about features of a database.

Comment: Yes this problem is not purely related to code, but if anyone had tried to upgrade any chunk from the application side or any other way to solve this problem

Answer (score 0):

IPv6 support was added to Greenplum Database 4.2.

According to the [release notes](https://community.emc.com/docs/DOC-13009):

> As the address exhaustion of Internet Protocol version 4 (IPv4)
>   approaches, support of its successor, Internet Protocol version 6
>   (IPv6), has become more and more important.
>
> This release of Greenplum Database provides support for IPv6 as well
>   as IPv4 addressing. This new support is transparent to end-users.
>
> Greenplum Database 4.2 supports IPV6 only, IPV4 only, as well as dual
>   stack environments for client-master connections, as follows:
>
> - Exclusive IPv6 environment (Master Server, Segment Hosts, Clients)
> - Exclusive IPv4 environment (Master Server, Segment Hosts, Clients)
> - IPv6 with dual-stack master:
> - Master Server and Standby Server support both IPv4 and IPv6 client connections (psql, odbc, jdbc, etc.)
> - All the Segment Servers must be exclusive IPv6
> - gpfdist Server supports the same network protocol as Segment Servers (IPv6)
>
> Note: Performance Monitor Web Server 4.1.1.8 supports Greenplum
>   Database running on either IPv4 or IPv6 environments noted above.
>
> When using IPv6, any references to IP addresses must be enclosed in
>   brackets [ ] as shown in the following examples:
>
> `gpfdist` example:
>
> ```
> CREATE EXTERNAL TABLE ext_gpfdist_table
> (num int)
> LOCATION ('gpfdist://[2620:0:170:610::11]:7777/ex.txt')
> FORMAT 'TEXT' (DELIMITER '|');
> ```
>
> Management utility (`gpdbrestore`) example:
>
> ```
> gpdbrestore -R [2620:0:170:610::11]:/path_to/master/gpseg-1/db_dumps/201108
> ```
>
> Note: Data Domain Boost does not support IPv6.

Note well that this does not mean that there aren't IPv6-related bugs; see the release notes for your version for a list of open IPv6 issues.